# Размещение файлов библиотек в подкаталоге

Tags: c++, c, dll

Как собрать программу на C++ c загружаемыми модулями таким образом, чтобы приложение находило файлы библиотечных модулей не в каталоге запуска, а в отдельном подкаталоге? Например, исполняемому файлу для работы требуется библиотечный файл "db2.dll", который расположен в папке "libs":

```
Application
|
+-- main.exe
+-- config.txt
+-- libs
    |
    +-- net.dll
    +-- db2.dll
```

Вопрос относится только к сборке приложений для ОС MS-Windows в разных компиляторах/сборщиках (MS-VC, MinGW, CodeBlocks и т.д.). Под Linux/Unix/*BSD для таких случаев просто используется параметр компилятора (линковщика): "-Wl,-rpath,./libs"

Comment: В Unix системах для этого существует специальный кэш динамического загрузчика, а как у вас, я не знаю.

Comment: Не знаю, но уверен, что всё упирается в динамический загрузчик и его возможности на конкретной платформе. Ещё могу представить версию с "трамплином", когда грузится вначале маленькая программа или скрипт, цель которой подставить через переменные окружения или ещё каким-то образом нужные пути к библиотекам (в Unix - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Comment: Забыл добавить, что во всех случаях компонуете программу как обычно, если, конечно, нет специальной "фичи" для желаемого поведения в самой среде сборки.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx

Comment: @0andry спасибо за линк, я тоже нашел похожую информацию. Нигде не забанили и ленью я тоже не грешу - просто почитайте об основной идее и задачах "StackOvrflow" - они немного отличаются от общения на LORe.

Comment: Не знаю, что такое LOR, но фактически я ссылку нашёл и привёл используя информацию, которую я написал во втором моём комментарии. Причём за несколько минут. Поэтому я и удивлён.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как ни странно, задача имеет решение и библиотеки, необходимые для приложения действительно можно положить в отдельный каталог и при этом не использовать динамическую загрузку библиотек, используя только статическое связывание. Это делается при помощи так называемых ***Assemblies*** (сборок), поддержка которых появилась в *Windows XP*.

Вкратце технология выглядит следующим образом. В исполняемый файл приложения внедряется манифест-файл, который предписывает приложению использовать некоторую сборку. Загрузчик исполняемых файлов читает этот манифест и ищет ***каталог со сборкой***, причём среди путей поиска присутствует и каталог с исполняемым файлом приложения.

---

Теперь более подробно, на примере и в деталях.

Создадим простейшее приложение на *C++*:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Будучи скомпилированным при помощи компилятора *MinGW* (MinGW-builds 6.3.0), это приложение в моём случае требует для своей работы файлы `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll` и `libwinpthread-1.dll`. При этом сам исполняемый файл импортирует только `libstdc++-6.dll`, которая, в свою очередь, импортирует две остальные. Назовём нашу "сборку", например, `libs`, создадим в каталоге с основным исполняемым файлом нашего приложения каталог `libs` и разместим внутри него три обозначенных выше DLL.

Далее создаём манифест. Имя файла манифеста должно состоять из имени сборки и иметь расширение `.manifest`, т.е., в нашем случае, `libs.manifest`. Содержимое файла должно быть следующим:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="libs" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" />
    <file name="libstdc++-6.dll" />
    <file name="libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll" />
    <file name="libwinpthread-1.dll" />
</assembly>
```

Особо следует отметить, что хотя наше приложение импортирует только одну библиотеку, в манифесте нужно прописать ***все***, иначе приложение работать не будет. Таким образом, у нас получилась следующая структура каталогов и файлов (`app.exe` - имя нашего приложения):

```
├─ app.exe
└─ libs
    ├─ libs.manifest
    ├─ libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
    ├─ libstdc++-6.dll
    └─ libwinpthread-1.dll
```

И, наконец, финальный аккорд! Создаём манифест, который будем внедрять в наше приложение. Пусть он лежит в файле с именем `manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="libs" version="1.0.0.0" language="*" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Параметры сборки, указанные в этом манифесте, должны совпадать с теми, что мы указали ранее. Теперь осталось только создать файл ресурсов, в котором указать на наш манифест

```
#include <windows.h>

CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "manifest.xml"
```

и прикомпоновать его к приложению (в случае *CMake*, например, указав имя файла ресурсов в списке исходников).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно слинковать библиотеку вручную во время исполнения функциями: LoadLibraryW, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary.

Пример:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    typedef void (*fn_t)(int a);

    HANDLE const dll = LoadLibraryW(L"libs\net.dll");
    if (dll == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fn_t fn = (fn_t)GetProcAddress(dll, "func_name");
    if (fn == NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(dll);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fn(123);

    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @bigov, в ответе как раз про run-time linking